# Rails 4.0 - How to get collection of objects based on an ID of a child object?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make a sort of search feature that will get all of the current_users' `members` that have an associated `game` with a specific `id`

I have tried:

```
@members = current_user.members.where(:games.id => params[:id])
```

But I get :

```
undefined method `id' for :games:Symbol
```

How would this be done in Rails?

**Update:** *Model associations*

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :games_members, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :games, :through => :games_members, :uniq => true
end

class GamesMembers < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key [:game_id, :member_id]
    belongs_to :members
    belongs_to :games
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :games_members, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :members, :through => :games_members, :uniq => true
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATED** *for future google users*

This I found is the correct way to achieve this goal

`@members = current_user.members.joins(:games_members).where(:games_members => {:game_id => params[:id]})`

Comment: Yes, this is a normal way, I think.

Comment: `#find` with `:all`? Really? It is deprecated since 3 and removed in 4.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier Then could you enlighten me with the new Rails 4 way instead of just down voting me? At least do it for the future people that happen along this post...

Comment: It isn't really hard to find [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Answer (score 2):

SnareChops,

I don't think you need the `has_many :games_members` in either models. Try without it. Instead of that you need to change to `has_and_belongs_to_many :games` from members, and `has_and_belongs_to_many :members` from games. The whole relationship should not be with the middle table `games_members` but rather `member.games` and `game.members`.

So then, if associations are set up the right way, it should then be something like:

```
@members = current_user.members.joins( :games ).where( games: { id: params[id] } )
```

Let me know if you need clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

The where is to find a column name, in this case a column of members table dont a reference:

this should work:

```
 @members = current_user.members.each { |m|
  m.games.each { |g|
    g.id == params[:id]
  }
 }
```

please test.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the foreign key field `game_id` for `Member` model? If so, try this:

```
@members = current_user.members.where(game_id: params[:id])
```

Comment: This is a many to many relationship with a join table so I don't have a column game_id. Thank you though.

Comment: Ok. What type of the association do you use between `Member` and `Game`, `habtm` or `has_many through`?

Comment: I am currently using `has_many through`. I'll post the code above.